# Url.Action is how to reformat URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am creating an MVC4 application.
In my contract controller overview page i have an **Url.Action**

```
int teller = 0;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Contract",new { id = teller })">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractMSFNo)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StageCode)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValidFromView)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValidToView)</td>

                    </tr>
                </a>

                teller++;
            }
```

I need to pass the id. I am  using id in the ActionLink details in Contract Controller

my controller is

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            //code

            return View(contract);
        }
```

When i click on the link **Url generated** is

`http://localhost:4826/Contract/Details/0`
**/0** is the id

i want my Url to be `http://localhost:4826/Contract/Details`

i know this can be acheived thru **Html.Actionlink** but it is my compulsion to use **Url.Action**. Can it be acheived with **Url.Action**

Comment: Surely you need `ID`. How you will get the value of `ID` when you don pass it when user clicks on one of the links. Whatever you are doing is good.

Comment: Thats what i am asking, is there any way that my url should appear `http://localhost:4826/Contract/Details` (i.e without id)?

Comment: Then you have to create forms, store `ID` in hiddenfield and submit form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done by routing or ActionLink. But you may try to use session.

1) Add to your controller new method to save your id to session:

```
public JsonResult Save(int id)
{
    Session["ID"] = id;
    return Json("Success");
}
```

2) Add jQuery method to save data in session from View and delete parameter from Url.Action:

```
<a class="mylink" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Contract")"></a>

<script>
$(".mylink").click(function(){
  var data = { id : teller}; //**teller is from your example
  $.get("@Url.Action("Details", "Contract")", data)
});

</script>
```

3) Change your Details ActionResult to get id from session:

```
public ActionResult Details()
        {
            var id = (int)Session["ID"];

           //code

            return View(contract);
        }
```

**P.S:** Ask your client, how he expects to give sombody external links. It will be impossible if url doesn't have a parameter. And it is very bad for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your URL without the `id` parameter, simply don't pass it to the `Url.Action()` method, as follows:

```
@Url.Action("Details", "Contract")
```

Comment: No i need to pass the ID. We are using id in the ActionLink details in Contract Controller.

Comment: You 'need to pass the Id', yet you 'want my Url to be http://localhost:4826/Contract/Details'?

Comment: "yes. this is the requirment of client" I am sorry, but here I have to ask: does your client know better than you about web programming and passing parameters to URLs? If yes, ask him to show how he does, if not, then ask him to let you do the job...

Answer (score 0):

If you add like {id=teller} then route automatically add id parameters end of the link. If you don't need id parameters for this url you need to remove

```
new { id = teller }
```

Final version like this

```
@Url.Action("Details", "Contract")
```

Comment: No i need to pass the ID. We are using id in the ActionLink details in Contract Controller

Comment: Ok then if this is a detail page (you have only one id) you can use session or something like this. Otherwise I don't know any other way to pass the Id without paramaters.

Comment: no actually there are many ids ...  code is  `foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Contract",new { id = teller })">`

Answer (score 0):

OK, reading this comment: "no actually there are many ids ... code is foreach (var item in Model) { ", I am not sure I understand what you really want to achieve. You are passing a parameter to the view, which can have only one value. Are you sure that you are not looking for something like:

```
foreach (var item in Model) 
{ 
   <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Contract",@item.ID>
   ...
}
```

instead? The fact the ID is visible or not in the URL seems to be another problem, no ?